Is there a more precise (i.e. narrower) term for "loaded question"?
Consider the following scenario:
Earlier, Person A stated many times that he/she is a life-long teetotaler.
Now, this Person A is being interviewed by Person B whose purpose is to make Person A look bad; specifically, to let the audience know, implicitly, that Person A is a drunk.
Person B:
"So, have you stopped drinking cognac in the morning?"
That is more of a statement - or an accusation - than a question.
It could be categorized as a "leading question" or "loaded question," but isn't there a more precise term that would imply that Person B's purpose is to get Person A to admit, implicitly, that he/she is a drunk? Some kind of logical fallacy, perhaps?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is properly called the fallacy of complex question (or, as Wikipedia notes, it's also called "trick question, multiple question, fallacy of presupposition, or plurium interrogationum). Wikipedia states further:

It (complex question) is committed when someone asks a question that presupposes something that has not been proven or accepted by all the people involved.

And it may be fallacious or true, as follows:

Legitimately complex question (not a fallacy): a question that assumes something that the hearer would readily agree to. For example, "Who is the monarch of the United Kingdom?" assumes that there is a place called the United Kingdom and that it has a monarch, both true.
Illegitimately complex question: "Who is the King of France?" would commit the complex question fallacy because while it assumes there is a place called France (true), it also assumes France currently has a king (false). But since answering this question does not seem to incriminate or otherwise embarrass the speaker, it is complex but not really a loaded question.

And, finally,

When a complex question contains controversial presuppositions (often with loaded language—having an unspoken and often emotive implication), it is known as a loaded question.

